# Could two SaaS applications reside in one Cloud instance?

Tags: cloud, saas

Could two SaaS applications reside in one Cloud instance?

Under what circumstances does it happen? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the cloud implementation, 'Cloud' is a pretty non-specific term referring only to hosting on a shared platform on the web. Some implementations provide a VM others provide only services. If you get a VM you can run lots of things on it. If you get a service instance you normally pay per individual instance so would normally only run 1 application on that.

Comment: The cloud here is referred to IaaS, where SaaS can be deployed on it.